# Styling CSS of Programmatically created classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Another component in my site creates span's with the class HighlightCOLOR where COLOR is any html color.

I then need to style the css the make the span that color.  I can do this obviously by creating css classes for each color and then style the background color the named color.  For example:

```
.HighlightMagenta
    {
        background-color:magenta;
    }
```

Is there a more elegant solution that simply writing css for each possible color?

Note: I can't change the structure described above. Its relevant for too many other things and the inelegant solution works well enough not not warrant a rebuild. I am happy to use javascript solutions, but would prefer a pure CSS solution. I don't do Jquery.

**To clarify based on questions below:**

The issue is that my html is being populated with unstyled spans of unknown (but predictable) class names.  The class names are in the format HighlightColor where Color is an html color.  I then need to style these classes with css that corresponds to the color named in the class title.

Comment: If you want to choose between whatever colour then classes might not be relevant at all? I simply don't understand the issue.

Comment: Almost similar to @bestprogrammerintheworld's comment. If you have multiple such colors and the color is the only property of the class, why not assign it directly as inline `style` instead of a class? In any case, what you are looking to achieve is not possible with CSS currently. Even pre-processors won't help here because you still need a static list of colors for which classes are required.

Comment: good luck creating and naming 16,777,216 classes mate.

Comment: edited in post itself to clarify

Comment: if you know the classes already , what is the specific problem?

Comment: @charlietfl **"unknown (but predictable) class names"**

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this is not possible. Only if you will create 16,777,216 classes/HTML lines as @Banana Mentioned.

Comment: where are the predictable class names coming from?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanWahdan, not possible at all? or not possible with pure css?

Comment: Not every strange and unclear things are possible with pure CSS. Why not to use `style` HTML attribute at least?

Comment: @maioman they are being rendered by another team member.  However, for the sake of not getting told to tell them to change it, lets imagine that I'm serving html saved from a DB, and that the span's of the formatting above are already in the db entries.

Comment: @COMisHARD i might have something for you, not sure if its what you are looking for but might be useful. hold on.

Comment: You might actually find a color name matching library and parse the classNames if such a library is found

Comment: Ok, if you imaging something, why you are preventing of use the proper tools like JQuery or pure JavaScript?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh, I'd definitely be happy with a pure JS solution.  Just don't known or do JQuery yet.

Comment: get the full list from other team member along with matching hex/rgb values

Comment: Can you please give us a list of your predicted classes? How many are there?

Comment: @charlietfl I appreciate the help. I know I could do something like that. I just thought this was an interesting puzzle and was hoping that there was a more elegant solution. If not: thats life.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/maio/t5vyn9ag/

Comment: Do you potentially have a list of possible colours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get all elements with those highlight classes and get the color name, and simply set the styling to it using JavaScript.

in my example i assume that those spans only have 1 class and its the color class, but you can easily get them even if they have other classes too.

if those spans are created dynamically, then run the function each time after new spans are created:

```js
processColors();

function processColors() {
  coloredClasses = document.querySelectorAll('span[class^="Highlight"]');
  for (i = 0; i < coloredClasses.length; i++) {
    CurrName = coloredClasses[i].className.split("Highlight")[1];
    coloredClasses[i].style["background"] = CurrName;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="HighlightRED">Colored Span</span>
<span class="HighlightMAGENTA">Colored Span</span>
<span class="HighlightBLACK">Colored Span</span>
<span class="HighlightNAVY">Colored Span</span>
<span class="HighlightYELLOW">Colored Span</span>
<span class="HighlightGREEN">Colored Span</span>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but not a pure CSS solution.

Comment: I should learn to read comments more. My mistake, upvoted your answer anyways :)

Comment: Also shouldn't background-color be set to avoid ruining other things set in background?

Comment: you're welcome :) and @RishavKundu yes you are right, but styling is up to op. the point of the answer was retrieval of the colored classes :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add style tag by javascript dynamically.

Use `[class*="Highlight"]` to get all elements which class contains word `Highlight`.

Then for each div, find its color name either use string operation or regex, then add it to either an `Object` or a `Set` to maintain its unique, then for each color, create a `style` tag to added those rules.

```js
var head = head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style = document.createElement('style');
var targetDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="Highlight"]');
var colors = {};

var len = targetDivs.length;
var i, color, matches;
var colorString = /Highlight([a-zA-z]+)/;
var matches;
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
  matches = targetDivs[i].className.match(colorString);
  if (matches) {
    colors[matches[0]] = matches[1].toLowerCase();
  }
};

var classNames = Object.keys(colors);
classNames.forEach(function(className) {
  var color = colors[className];
  var stl = 'div.' + className + '{ background-color: ' + color + '}\n';
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stl));
});

head.appendChild(style);
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test HighlightMagenta"></div>
<div class="HighlightRed test"></div>
<div class="HighlightBlue"></div>
```

Comment: Best solution! Unless the colour is not really a colour, of course.

Comment: You can validate it against https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors I think to make foolproof.

Answer (score 2):

While this may not be the solution you are looking for. If you want a pure css solution you'll need to declare all those classes in css.

Manually this will take a lot of time, but I suggest you look into css preprocessors like LESS or SASS (I prefer the latter).

They accept functions and will then "compile" into a css sheet which you can use for your website.

You could write a function to generate all those classes with the rules you want them to have.

[LESS](http://lesscss.org)

[SASS](http://sass-lang.com)

Comment: This was helpful but the JS answer is more what I was looking for I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically add a styleSheet and then use `styleSheet.insertRule(rule, index)` to insert the styles from a list of predefined color names ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ob11rr7/5/)):

```
addColorRules(); // run when head element is available

function addColorRules() {
    var style = document.createElement('style'), // create new stylesheet element
        styleSheet;

    document.head.appendChild(style); // append to head

    styleSheet = style.sheet; // get the sheet from the element

    getColors().forEach(function (color) { // iterate color names
        var rule = '.Highlight' + color + '{background-color: ' + color + '; }'; // create the rule
        styleSheet.insertRule(rule, styleSheet.cssRules.length); // insert rule to style sheet
    });
}


function getColors() { // a list of predefined color names
    return ["Aliceblue", "Antiquewhite", "Aqua", "Aquamarine", "Azure", "Beige", "Bisque", "Black", "Blanchedalmond", "Blue", "Blueviolet", "Brown"]; // include all color names
}
```

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript could solve the problem:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Highlight').each(function(elem){
        $(this).css('background-color',$(this).data('color'))
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qtbrsbuh/

Comment: why would you do this? If the colors are known they should be added to css stylesheet. Creates a lot of extra work adding attributes in html where a simple stylesheet rule would do it. Just because it works doesn't it make it practical or scaleable